# Webpack config with "target: 'node'" and "type: 'module'" throws 'require is not defined'

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, es6-modules

When running my webpack config for an express server that uses ES6 modules, has `"type": "module"` defined in `package.json` and uses `target: 'node'` it fails with an an error `ReferenceError: require is not defined`.

When looking at the processed javascript file i see the following statements that cause this error:

```
/******/ (() => { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    "use strict";
/******/    var __webpack_modules__ = ({

/***/ "body-parser":
/*!******************************!*\
  !*** external "body-parser" ***!
  \******************************/
/***/ ((module) => {

module.exports = require("body-parser");

/***/ }),
```

Why does webpack include this code?
The server runs totally fine when not processed with webpack.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by adding

```
experiments: {
  ...
  outputModule: true,
},
output: {
  ...
  chunkFormat: 'module', 
}
```

To my webpack.config.js